# (Taylor's theorem) Proving that $\sin(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion

I'm starting a class on Advanced Mathematics I next semester and I found a sheet of the class'es 2012 final exams, so I'm slowly trying to solve the exercises in it or find the general layout. I will be posting a lot of questions with the exercises I find challenging, and I would like to ask for any help or methodologies that will make it easier for me to solve.

I understand the whole ordeal is categorized as **"homework"**, but any assistance would be appreciated, as I'm completely clueless and I would like to be prepared.

The following exercise is $Ex. 10$, graded for $10\%$.

> Define Taylor's Theorem and prove that $\sin(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$.

From the class'es page, I've got the definition of *Taylor's theorem* along with the following equation that resembles a **Sum**:

$$f(x)=f(x_0)+\frac{f'(x_0)}{1!}(x-x_0)+\frac{f''(x_0)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2+\frac{f'''(x_0)}{3!}(x-x_0)^3+\cdots+\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(x_0)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}$$

Apart from the similarity, I do not know how to continue. Do I take the **second** part of the equation and try to find a closed type that leads to sin(x)?

Comment: Well, you can try to expand $\sin x$ at $x_0=0$ by using the definition of taylor series

Comment: Tiny thing:  $f(x_0)=\frac{f^{(0)}(x_0)}{0!}{(x-x_0)}^0$; this means even for $n=0$ the terms really look exactly the same.

Comment: I wrote a [blog post](http://davidlowryduda.com/?p=1520) about this and related topics for my students a while ago.

Comment: @mixedmath that is extremely useful, thank you. Currently reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$f(x) = sin x \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   f(0)= 0\\ f'(x) = cos x \ \ \ \ \ \ f'(0)=1 \\ f''(x) = -sinx \ \ f''(0)=0 \\ f'''(x) = -cosx \ \ f'''(0) = -1 \\ f^{(4)}(x)=sinx \ \ \ f(0)=0 $$

The derivatives repeat in a cycle of four, from Taylor series definition we have that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)^{n}}{n!}$$ Take $a=0$ and the result follows.

Comment: I'm ending up at $\sin{x} = \dfrac{1}{1!}x - \dfrac{1}{3!}x^3 + \dfrac{1}{5!}x^5 - \dfrac{1}{7!}x^7$ which yes, is the same as the $\sum$. In an exam environment, would it be okay to, without proof, claim that this expansion is equivalent to the $\sum$, and finish my solution there?

Comment: From experience, I would say yes, these series are quite common to appear and as you did yourself not so difficult to derive.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Consider $\cos(x)+i\sin(x)=e^{ix}$. Use the Taylor expansion of $e^y$ around $y=0$; in the result, replace $y$ by $ix$ and collect together the real and imaginary parts. So, knowing $e^y$, you have both Taylor expansions ($\cos(x)$) and ($\sin(x)$).

**Added later**

$$e^y=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{y^k}{k!}$$ $$e^{ix}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(ix)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{i^k x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{i^k x^k}{k!}$$ Now spplit the summation over the odd and even values of $k$. So,$$e^{ix}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^{2n} x^{2n}}{2n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^{2n+1} x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^{2n} x^{2n}}{2n!}+i\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^{2n} x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ $$e^{ix}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n} x^{2n}}{2n!}+i\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\cos(x)+i \sin(x)$$

Comment: I really am sorry but I can't make heads or tails of your answer :-( How would the expansion of $e^y$ work?

Comment: Forgot to thank you for the elaborate answer nontheless.

Comment: You are very welcome ! I shall add to my post right now. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

HINTS/GUIDANCE

You need to know that if you differentiate $\sin x$ you get $\cos x$, and if you differentiate $\cos x$ you get $-\sin x$. So the derivatives toggle backwards and forwards between $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ but you need care with the minus signs.

Obviously take $x_0=0$. The answer clearly has powers of $x$, not powers of $(x-x_0)$ and anyway the lhs has no visible $x_0$, so $x_0$ must be $0$.

And of course you need to know that $\sin 0=0,\cos 0=1$.